# Plotting a surface with TikZ and pgfplots from a data set

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to plot a surface from the following data set (625 points) using tikz and pgfplots

```
-0.5 -0.5 3.46623e-13
-0.5 -0.46 4.23572e-12
-0.5 -0.42 2.795e-11
-0.5 -0.38 1.30946e-10
-0.5 -0.34 4.72889e-10
-0.5 -0.3 1.38613e-09
-0.5 -0.26 3.42939e-09
-0.5 -0.22 7.35667e-09
-0.5 -0.18 1.39511e-08
-0.5 -0.14 2.37587e-08
-0.5 -0.1 3.6855e-08
-0.5 -0.06 5.28058e-08
-0.5 -0.02 7.08997e-08
-0.5 0.02 9.06011e-08
-0.5 0.06 1.12124e-07
-0.5 0.1 1.37092e-07
-0.5 0.14 1.69447e-07
-0.5 0.18 2.17247e-07
-0.5 0.22 2.9748e-07
-0.5 0.26 4.50232e-07
-0.5 0.3 7.75008e-07
-0.5 0.34 1.47607e-06
-0.5 0.38 2.57253e-06
-0.5 0.42 2.57163e-06
-0.5 0.46 9.19719e-07
-0.46 -0.5 4.23572e-12
-0.46 -0.46 3.36874e-08
-0.46 -0.42 3.7432e-07
-0.46 -0.38 2.33649e-06
-0.46 -0.34 1.02025e-05
-0.46 -0.3 3.35122e-05
-0.46 -0.26 8.80409e-05
-0.46 -0.22 0.000193057
-0.46 -0.18 0.00036258
-0.46 -0.14 0.000593124
-0.46 -0.1 0.000855392
-0.46 -0.06 0.00109763
-0.46 -0.02 0.00126204
-0.46 0.02 0.00130675
-0.46 0.06 0.00122209
-0.46 0.1 0.00103342
-0.46 0.14 0.000789457
-0.46 0.18 0.000555669
-0.46 0.22 0.000371223
-0.46 0.26 0.00023548
-0.46 0.3 0.000146125
-0.46 0.34 9.72368e-05
-0.46 0.38 8.08009e-05
-0.46 0.42 5.57046e-05
-0.46 0.46 1.59007e-05
-0.42 -0.5 2.795e-11
-0.42 -0.46 3.7432e-07
-0.42 -0.42 3.55719e-06
-0.42 -0.38 1.97694e-05
-0.42 -0.34 8.55822e-05
-0.42 -0.3 0.000289574
-0.42 -0.26 0.000778258
-0.42 -0.22 0.00173953
-0.42 -0.18 0.00333729
-0.42 -0.14 0.0055946
-0.42 -0.1 0.00828945
-0.42 -0.06 0.0109435
-0.42 -0.02 0.0130521
-0.42 0.02 0.0141784
-0.42 0.06 0.0139847
-0.42 0.1 0.0126919
-0.42 0.14 0.0105715
-0.42 0.18 0.0081194
-0.42 0.22 0.00572528
-0.42 0.26 0.00368559
-0.42 0.3 0.00215531
-0.42 0.34 0.00119561
-0.42 0.38 0.000678065
-0.42 0.42 0.000288686
-0.42 0.46 5.57047e-05
-0.38 -0.5 1.30946e-10
-0.38 -0.46 2.33649e-06
-0.38 -0.42 1.97694e-05
-0.38 -0.38 8.79028e-05
-0.38 -0.34 0.000327264
-0.38 -0.3 0.00110666
-0.38 -0.26 0.00307516
-0.38 -0.22 0.00699941
-0.38 -0.18 0.0136182
-0.38 -0.14 0.0232146
-0.38 -0.1 0.0353694
-0.38 -0.06 0.0485681
-0.38 -0.02 0.060142
-0.38 0.02 0.0672238
-0.38 0.06 0.0682955
-0.38 0.1 0.0632371
-0.38 0.14 0.0536222
-0.38 0.18 0.0415687
-0.38 0.22 0.0292336
-0.38 0.26 0.0184079
-0.38 0.3 0.0103754
-0.38 0.34 0.00538385
-0.38 0.38 0.00240944
-0.38 0.42 0.000678066
-0.38 0.46 8.08011e-05
-0.34 -0.5 4.72889e-10
-0.34 -0.46 1.02025e-05
-0.34 -0.42 8.55822e-05
-0.34 -0.38 0.000327263
-0.34 -0.34 0.00090475
-0.34 -0.3 0.00254178
-0.34 -0.26 0.00715854
-0.34 -0.22 0.0168892
-0.34 -0.18 0.033278
-0.34 -0.14 0.0572468
-0.34 -0.1 0.0882414
-0.34 -0.06 0.122187
-0.34 -0.02 0.152389
-0.34 0.02 0.171939
-0.34 0.06 0.176168
-0.34 0.1 0.164572
-0.34 0.14 0.140281
-0.34 0.18 0.108463
-0.34 0.22 0.0751451
-0.34 0.26 0.0464551
-0.34 0.3 0.0263575
-0.34 0.34 0.0136861
-0.34 0.38 0.00538385
-0.34 0.42 0.00119561
-0.34 0.46 9.72369e-05
-0.3 -0.5 1.38613e-09
-0.3 -0.46 3.35122e-05
-0.3 -0.42 0.000289574
-0.3 -0.38 0.00110666
-0.3 -0.34 0.00254178
-0.3 -0.3 0.00487513
-0.3 -0.26 0.011007
-0.3 -0.22 0.0268406
-0.3 -0.18 0.0547658
-0.3 -0.14 0.0946771
-0.3 -0.1 0.144474
-0.3 -0.06 0.197987
-0.3 -0.02 0.245347
-0.3 0.02 0.276067
-0.3 0.06 0.283042
-0.3 0.1 0.264651
-0.3 0.14 0.224635
-0.3 0.18 0.171182
-0.3 0.22 0.116546
-0.3 0.26 0.0738816
-0.3 0.3 0.0465582
-0.3 0.34 0.0263575
-0.3 0.38 0.0103754
-0.3 0.42 0.00215531
-0.3 0.46 0.000146125
-0.26 -0.5 3.42938e-09
-0.26 -0.46 8.80409e-05
-0.26 -0.42 0.000778257
-0.26 -0.38 0.00307516
```

I tried with the following code:

```
 \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{calc}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
 \begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{axis}
             \addplot3[surf] file {data_file.dat};
         \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

But the result I get is the following:

[image]

I tried to use gnuplot in TikZ or to add shader=internp or other ideas that I found on the web but nothing happened to give a better result.

Can please someone help me

Best

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by myself finally:

It is sufficient to change the way the data are stored to get a matrix form, as in the following example

```
(0,0,5) (1,0,3) (2,0,7)

(0,1,2) (1,1,4) (2,1,5)

(0,2,2) (1,2,5) (2,2,6)
```